# How do I sort this array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I grouped an array using the following script

```
$grouped_array = array();       
foreach($ungrouped_array as $item) {
    //group them by id
    $grouped_array[$item['id']][] = $item;
}
```

Now this grouped array looks like this

```
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
  }

  [6]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "6"
    }
  }

  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "2"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["sub"]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["sub"]=>
      string(1) "2"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(1) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "2"
    }
  }
}
```

I have deleted the most part of the array to make it shorter but there is no `[0]` field in this grouped array
 All array fields are given the name of `[id]`'s value. I have no problem with that, I just have to short it again by `[ID]`

any suggestion will be great.

Comment: Are you looking for [`ksort`](http://php.net/ksort)?

Comment: Should only items be sorted, that are in a group?

Comment: You use ungrouped_array in your foreach, but we have nu clue what is in it. In general try somthing like foreach($Arr as $key => $val) to keep the keys and the vals.

Comment: @Ron I need to sort this array by ID or array number (both are same) like 1, 2, 6

Comment: @deceze great!! `ksort()` worked just like I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work to get 1, 2, 6:

```
<?php
$grouped_array = array();       
foreach($ungrouped_array as $item) {
    $grouped_array[$item['id']][] = $item;
}

// sort by key.
ksort( $grouped_array, SORT_NUMERIC );

print_r( $grouped_array );
```